# how can i extract information from the HTML code

Tags: python

This code is a Single line of .html file which is extracted from the HTML file with a  unique  identifier "|Rv0153c|":

```
<TR><TD><small style=font-family:courier> >M. tuberculosis H37Rv|Rv0153c|ptbB<br />MAVRELPGAWNFRDVADTATALRPGRLFRSSELSRLDDAGRATLRRLGITDVADLRSSRE<br />VARRGPGRVPDGIDVHLLPFPDLADDDADDSAPHETAFKRLLTNDGSNGESGESSQSIND<br />AATRYMTDEYRQFPTRNGAQRALHRVVTLLAAGRPVLTHCFAGKDRTGFVVALVLEAVGL<br />DRDVIVADYLRSNDSVPQLRARISEMIQQRFDTELAPEVVTFTKARLSDGVLGVRAEYLA<br />AARQTIDETYGSLGGYLRDAGISQATVNRMRGVLLG<br /></small><TR><td><b><big>Blastp: <a href="http://tuberculist.epfl.ch/blast_output/Rv0153c.fasta.out"> Pre-computed results</a></big></b><TR><td><b><big>TransMembrane prediction using Hidden Markov Models: <a href="http://tuberculist.epfl.ch/tmhmm/Rv0153c.html"> TMHMM</a></big></b><base target="_blank"/><TR><td><b><big>Genomic sequence</big></b><br /><br /><form action="dnaseq.php" method="get">
```

i want to write a code which is able to extract the given information(given below) in a given format from this line of .html code:

```
>M. tuberculosis H37Rv|Rv0153c|ptbB
MAVRELPGAWNFRDVADTATALRPGRLFRSSELSRLDDAGRATLRRLGITDVADLRSSRE
VARRGPGRVPDGIDVHLLPFPDLADDDADDSAPHETAFKRLLTNDGSNGESGESSQSIND
AATRYMTDEYRQFPTRNGAQRALHRVVTLLAAGRPVLTHCFAGKDRTGFVVALVLEAVGL
DRDVIVADYLRSNDSVPQLRARISEMIQQRFDTELAPEVVTFTKARLSDGVLGVRAEYLA
AARQTIDETYGSLGGYLRDAGISQATVNRMRGVLLG
```

Comment: you should probably check out regular expressions.  Python has an re module which can handle this for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what you are looking for is an HTML parser:
[Simple HTML and XHTML parser](http://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html)

Comment: thanks for your valuable suggestion HTML parser is great for my work just 3 line code can be able to do exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Python and regular expression library.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
sentence = '<TR><TD><small style=font-family:courier> >M. tuberculosis H37Rv|Rv0153c|ptbB<br />MAVRELPGAWNFRDVADTATALRPGRLFRSSELSRLDDAGRATLRRLGITDVADLRSSRE<br />VARRGPGRVPDGIDVHLLPFPDLADDDADDSAPHETAFKRLLTNDGSNGESGESSQSIND<br />AATRYMTDEYRQFPTRNGAQRALHRVVTLLAAGRPVLTHCFAGKDRTGFVVALVLEAVGL<br />DRDVIVADYLRSNDSVPQLRARISEMIQQRFDTELAPEVVTFTKARLSDGVLGVRAEYLA<br />AARQTIDETYGSLGGYLRDAGISQATVNRMRGVLLG<br /></small><TR><td><b><big>Blastp: <a href="http://tuberculist.epfl.ch/blast_output/Rv0153c.fasta.out"> Pre-computed results</a></big></b><TR><td><b><big>TransMembrane prediction using Hidden Markov Models: <a href="http://tuberculist.epfl.ch/tmhmm/Rv0153c.html"> TMHMM</a></big></b><base target="_blank"/><TR><td><b><big>Genomic sequence</big></b><br /><br /><form action="dnaseq.php" method="get">'   
print re.sub('<[^>]*>', '',  sentence)
```

HTH.

Comment: You're not actually using BeautifulSoup here, you're merely using a regex.